# How to sync data across ServiceNow to Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, synchronization, servicenow-rest-api

I'm looking for a way to have all data and updates on ServiceNow automatically populate and update on AzureDevops as the team slowly transitions from ServiceNow to Azure. So far the methods I found are using external applications and apis which as not as secure or reliable. Are there any built in way to leverage connections and webhooks to sync data?

It is not necessary for data to flow from Azure to ServiceNow. The requirement is having permanent syncing from ServiceNow to Azure Devops.

The solutions I have found so far all require external pulgins and applications and for security reasons i would like to avoid this route.

Comment: afaik, no - and somebody correct me if i am wrong. If you wish a permanent sync solution it is usually a 3rd party application, that does the syncing. We usually did it with a scheduled mechanism and implemented the functionality by ourself. Or we used existing 3rd party apps. As i see it, you have a trade-off between self-development effort and using an existing application with security concerns.

Comment: What secure third party solutions are available for this case.